# Como alterar a pasta www (DocumentRoot) para outra partição no Apache 2.4 (Ubuntu 14.04)?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Eu tentei alterar a **Document Root** alterando os arquivos *default.conf* em sites-available. Porém eu recebo a mensagem que não tenho permissão para acessar o localhost.
Alguém saberia dizer qual o procedimento exato? Posso ter esquecido de algo.
***- Apache 2.4.7
- Ubuntu 14.04***

Comment: Em `sites-enabled` existe um *link* `000-default` apontando para o arquivo em questão? Como estão as permissões da nova pasta que deve servir como *root* e seu respectivo arquivo *index.html* (tente setar `755`)? Finalmente não se esqueça de resetar o servidor após modificar suas configurações (`sudo service apache2 restart`). Mais informações sobre os procedimentos podem ser encontradas em [Ubuntu Documentation: HTTPD - Apache2 Web Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/httpd.html) (em inglês)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

É necessário alterar dois arquivos de configuração do apache:

Arquivo 1:

```
   sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Alterar a linha:

```
   <Directory /var/www/>
```

Para

Fica assim:

```
   <Directory /home/usuario/diretorio_que_vc_quiser/>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
   </Directory>
```

Arquivo 2:

```
   $ sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
   ou
   $ sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf
```

Alterar a linha:

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www
```

para

```
    DocumentRoot /home/usuario/diretorio_que_vc_quiser/
```

Não esqueça de reiniciar o apache depois:

```
    $ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Parabéns, muito bom consegui resolver o problema sem dificuldades e rápido.

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema, eu tinha esquecido de

```
<Directory /home/usuario/diretorio_que_vc_quiser/>
```

no arquivo /etc/apache2/apache2.conf