# Laravel em servidor dedicado

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tentando instalar o `laravel` em uma subpasta dentro de `public_html`, dentro da pasta onde esta a aplicação criei o seguinte `.htaccess`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Só que agora quando acesso atraves da URL só recebo o erro;

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Verifiquei em meu arquivo de rotas se o caminho estava correto e esta.

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'dashboard.login', function() {
  return view('dashboard.auth.login');
}]);
```

Consegui entrar o "erro", eu só consigo acessar a aplicação se eu colocar `/public` depois do dominio, mas estou usando este `.htaccess` que comentei acima e ele deveria remover este "public" correto?

Comment: Você pode setar o `document root` do Apache para a pasta `public` da sua aplicação, resolveria o problema

Comment: @AmandaLima a document root esta sendo usada pelo site e esta aplicação tem que ficar dentro de uma pasta na public, entendeu?

Comment: Qual o sistema operacional do servidor?

Comment: @AmandaLima ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Poderá encontrar uma resposta detalhada : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14150/como-alterar-a-pasta-www-documentroot-para-outra-parti%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-apache-2-4-ubunt

Comment: @AmandaLima não é bem isso que eu preciso, como eu disse, eu não quero alterar o acesso padrao da public_html

Comment: @RafaelAcioly eu geralmente nem altero o .htaccess, simplesmente altero o redirecionamento para a public do laravel no painel de hospedagem. Por exemplo de "public_html" para "public_html/minha_aplicacao/public". Então quando acessam o domínio ou subdomínio que eu apontei ele já funciona direitinho.